# Is there any way to block javascript pop-overs in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript

Like the kind pointed to in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/nioKTol.jpg)

Many sites have these, and I find them highly annoying. Often you'll be reading an article and suddenly the pop-over blanks out the page and asks "WOULDN'T YOU JUST LOVE OUR EMAIL NEWSLETTER?!" - why no, no I wouldn't.

I'd love to get rid of these if possible.

I'm using FF 38.01 in Win 7 x64.

Comment: Not a web development guru but looks and sounds like  3rd party javascript is still enabled/allowed    in chrome at least  this is  stopped in chrome://settings  and adjusting content params to disable 3rd party JS and popups unless "white-listed" can't confirm the same in firefox but would assume its at least similar  procedure

Comment: You can always just disable javascript otherwise use an add-on to selectively allow the javascript you want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes, they can be blocked quite easily using Adblock Plus or whatever, even Stylish will do.

*However*, there is no universal way of blocking them. Each site would name their elements differently and telling a legitimate/wanted fixed element from an unwanted one programmatically would be very difficult and very error-prone.

So nothing short of completely disabling JavaScript would help, and even then they could appear; it’s pure CSS, after all.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I don't mind blocking them per site, if the block will 'stick'. So in ABP, do I just use 'block element'?  Also, would NoScript work? I was kind of trying to avoid it because it seems like the nuclear option (not sure, i've not used it before).

Comment: NoScript might be overkill. Personally, I’d rather enjoy an interactive web with a few annoyances every here and there. If you go the Adblock route, I recommend the [Element Hiding Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/) add-on. It’s very helpful in selecting the “offending” HTML element and creating a filter from it.

Comment: oh wow, didn't know about the element hiding add-on. Thanks, I'll definitely try that.

Comment: It seems like there could be a universal blacklist/filter though that is shared by all users of some client-side mod addon like Stylish or GreaseMonkey. If every user's block choices were aggregated in the filter DB (and given some popularity threshold before being committed), all users would benefit. I'm really surprised something like this hasn't been implemented yet. Even ABP with the old school popup required filter subscriptions to work optimally. Is this really that different?